# How to print and assign properties to an object Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering how can I print and assigned following object that contains an array as a property?

```
var carreers = [
  {
    name: "Law",
    courses: [
      "Law I",
      "Law II"
     ]

  },
```

Comment: did you tried carreers[0].courses[0] like this?

Comment: Yes, but it did not work. I am trying to use Angular for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
for(var i =0; i < carreers.length; i++){
     console.log(carreers[i].name);
     console.log(carreers[i].courses);
     for(var j =0; j < carreers[i].courses.length; j++){
         console.log(' - ' + carreers[i].courses[j]);
      }
}
```

for angular:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in carreers">
     <p>{{data.name}}</p>
     <div ng-repeat="course in data.courses">
         <p> - {{course}}</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

to add course in a specific career

```
carreers[0].courses.push("Law III");
```

Display courses on select career

```
<select id="courses" ng-model="career">
   <option ng-repeat="career in data" value="{$index}">{career.name}</option>
</select>

<div ng-repeat="course in data[career].courses">{course}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I actually need to do that with ng-repeat!

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: Thank you man! It worked!! By any chance do you know how to add a course to a carrer. I have no idea how to push that

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Thank you! I think I already did that. I am new here lol. Please let me know if it is updated

Comment: Yes, that worked as well! Do you know how to create a filtering select by selecting a carreer and accodring to that, display the courses for that career?

Comment: user filter `<div ng-repeat="data in carreers | filter : {name: careerFilterSelect.name}: true">`

Comment: This is my first select   <select>
        <option value="">--Select carrer--</option>
        <option value="{{carrer.name}}" ng-repeat="carrer in carrers">{{carrer.name}}</option>
      </select>

Comment: The second one (The one that should be filtering according to the selection of the first select )  <select>
        <option value="">--Select Course--</option>
        <option value="" ng-repeat="data in carrers | filter : {name: careerFilterSelect.name}: true"></option>
      </select>

Comment: Do I have to create a function for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about angular. Use:

```
angular.forEach(carreers, function(career) { // this will internally do necessary null checks
    console.log(career); // Print career value.
    career.name = "test1" // Assign Value - value would be updated by reference
    angular.forEach(career.courses, function(course) {
        console.log(course); // Print course value.
        course.push("test12") // Assign Value
    });
});
```